# ngrx-store - Where to create AppState

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

So I am currently in the process of using angular 5 (for the first time, I have angularJS experience) and ngrx-store (for the first time) in a brand new application.

I think I understand the basics of ngrx well enough and am now trying to get my head around patterns of implementation to allow scalability.

Let us say that I have a RootModule, a CommonModule and then a module per functional area (which then have multiple sub modules in there). Currently, each functional area keeps a dataModel that represents the data structure it needs (which is then used to create whatever presentation models I need). For example, the 'People' area would have a 'Person' dataModel defined, the 'Inventory' area would have a 'Product' defined etc.

From what I understand of ngrx (which may be little - nothing), I would probably create a set of actions for people and then export them out as a constant (same for inventory). Then I would create a reducer for people and inventory with a switch case on my exported constant. This action and reducer files could then sit in their respective modules.

Now I come to AppState which will have Person as well as Product inside it. I am thoroughly confused about where to put AppState.

- Does it sit in CommonModule and I import dataModels from specific modules all into this file? (def seems wrong as my commonmodule would now be reliant on children modules).
- Do I move all my dataModels into CommonModule? (seems cleaner but still not quite right)

Appreciate any insight/input into a good way to design this!

Saagar